Automatically listing answer choices: either all in one line, or each answer choice in one line
I began typing my pdf file using overleaf. The material I have consists of Math MCQs. I faced many problem and decided not to continue typing before I fix these things first.
However, as commented in that post, it will be easier when I ask one question per post, and I totally agreed. For that I am posting this.

Requirement:
Whenever it is enough to place the answer choices in one single line, I need to do it automatically. Otherwise, each answer choice should appear in a different line.

For example:

This looks good, because the answer choices are short and fit in one line.
The following is also good, because one line is not enough to include all answer choices.


I saw (exam), but for me it was not helpful. I am not saying it is bad, but I am a new user and it looks so advanced for me. Probably it will be beneficial for me in future when I get some more basic things with LaTex.

My current code is:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcommand{\np}{%
  \par%
  \needspace{10\baselineskip}%
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
  \stepcounter{problem}%
  \textbf{Problem \theproblem:}\par
}
\newcommand{\ep}{\par\noindent\hrulefill}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\np 
If $f(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$, what is the value of $f'(0)$?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $0$
  \item $1$
  \item $\sqrt{2}$
  \item $2$
  \item $\pi$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Suppose that $f$ is a function on the interval $[1,3]$ such that $-1\le f(x)\le 1$ for all $x$ and $\int_{1}^{3}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$. How large can $\int_{0}^{3}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ be?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $8$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(3+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(2+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\log(2)$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets, and let $f:A\xrightarrow{}B$ and $g:B\xrightarrow{}C$ be functions. Which of the following is true?
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.,leftmargin=*]
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.
    \item If $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, then $g\,\circ\,f$ is bijective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is bijective, then $f\,\circ\,g$ is identically zero.
    \item If $f\,\circ\,g=g\,\circ\,f$, then both $f$ and $g$ cannot be simultaneously bijective.
    \item If $f\,\circ\,g$ is injective, then $g\,\circ\,f$ can be either $0$ or $1$.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item I and II only
  \item I and III only
  \item II and III only
  \item III only
  \item III, IV, V and VI only
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
The region bounded by the $x$-axis and the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ is rotated about the $x$-axis. What is the volume of the solid generated?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$
  \item $\pi$
  \item $2\pi$
  \item $\infty$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Let $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3+3x^2y-x$ for all real $x$ and $y$. Which of the following is true of $f$?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item There is an absolute minimum at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a relative maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{1}{3},-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a saddle point at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item There is an absolute maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item All critical values are on the line $y=x$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Find the general solution of
$$\displaystyle2\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+9\,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}-35y=0$$
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{\frac{5}{2}x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-\frac{5}{2}x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{5x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-5x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1\cos(5x)+C_2\cos(7x)$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Suppose today is Wednesday. What day of the week will it be $\displaystyle 10^{{10}^{10}}$ days from now?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item Sunday
   \item Monday
   \item Tuesday
   \item Wednesday
   \item Thursday
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\end{document}


Some people may suggest me to use a specific package/environment, but I do not know then how to apply that properly. So I hope this requirement can be done easily.

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Major Issue:
If there is no enough space, move the problem with its answer choices entirely to the next page. The following code does that actually:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcommand{\np}{%
  \par%
  \needspace{10\baselineskip}%
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
  \stepcounter{problem}%
  \textbf{Problem \theproblem:}\par
}
\newcommand{\ep}{\nopagebreak\vspace{-\parskip}\par\noindent\hrulefill\par\nopagebreak}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\np 
If $f(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$, what is the value of $f'(0)$?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $0$
  \item $1$
  \item $\sqrt{2}$
  \item $2$
  \item $\pi$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Suppose that $f$ is a function on the interval $[1,3]$ such that $-1\le f(x)\le 1$ for all $x$ and $\int_{1}^{3}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$. How large can $\int_{0}^{3}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ be?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $8$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(3+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(2+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\log(2)$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets, and let $f:A\xrightarrow{}B$ and $g:B\xrightarrow{}C$ be functions.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.,leftmargin=*]
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.
   
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item I and II only
  \item I and III only
  \item II and III only
  \item III only
  \item III, IV, V and VI only
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
The region bounded by the $x$-axis and the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ is rotated about the $x$-axis. What is the volume of the solid generated?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$
  \item $\pi$
  \item $2\pi$
  \item $\infty$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Let $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3+3x^2y-x$ for all real $x$ and $y$. Which of the following is true of $f$?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item There is an absolute minimum at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a relative maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{1}{3},-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a saddle point at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item There is an absolute maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item All critical values are on the line $y=x$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Find the general solution of
$$\displaystyle2\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+9\,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}-35y=0$$
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{\frac{5}{2}x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-\frac{5}{2}x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{5x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-5x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1\cos(5x)+C_2\cos(7x)$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Suppose today is Wednesday. What day of the week will it be $\displaystyle 10^{{10}^{10}}$ days from now?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item Sunday
   \item Monday
   \item Tuesday
   \item Wednesday
   \item Thursday
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
If $x^2+x=3$, then $x^4+x=$
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item $x^2+3$
   \item $4(3-x)$
   \item $3(x-1)$
   \item $6(2-x)$
   \item $3x$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\log(x)}\right)$
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item $x^2+3$
   \item $4(3-x)$
   \item $3(x-1)$
   \item $6(2-x)$
   \item $3x$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\end{document}


For illustration purpose, I have changed problem 3 to look shorter. See problem 4 is entirely in a new page, which is good.

You can grab the environment body so that it can be reset multiple ways, first try an inline list and if that is too wide, reset as a display list

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcommand{\np}{%
  \par%
  \needspace{10\baselineskip}%
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
  \stepcounter{problem}%
  \textbf{Problem \theproblem:}\par
}
\newcommand{\ep}{\par\noindent\hrulefill}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{anslist}{O{}b}
{%
  \sbox0{\begin{enumerate*}[#1]#2\end{enumerate*}}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
    \begin{enumerate}[#1]#2\end{enumerate}
  \else
    \par\noindent\usebox{0}\par
  \fi
}
{}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\np 
If $f(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$, what is the value of $f'(0)$?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $0$
  \item $1$
  \item $\sqrt{2}$
  \item $2$
  \item $\pi$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Suppose that $f$ is a function on the interval $[1,3]$ such that $-1\le f(x)\le 1$ for all $x$ and $\int_{1}^{3}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$. How large can $\int_{0}^{3}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ be?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $8$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(3+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(2+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\log(2)$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets, and let $f:A\xrightarrow{}B$ and $g:B\xrightarrow{}C$ be functions. Which of the following is true?
\begin{anslist}[label=\Roman*.,leftmargin=*]
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.
    \item If $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, then $g\,\circ\,f$ is bijective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is bijective, then $f\,\circ\,g$ is identically zero.
    \item If $f\,\circ\,g=g\,\circ\,f$, then both $f$ and $g$ cannot be simultaneously bijective.
    \item If $f\,\circ\,g$ is injective, then $g\,\circ\,f$ can be either $0$ or $1$.
\end{anslist}
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item I and II only
  \item I and III only
  \item II and III only
  \item III only
  \item III, IV, V and VI only
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
The region bounded by the $x$-axis and the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ is rotated about the $x$-axis. What is the volume of the solid generated?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$
  \item $\pi$
  \item $2\pi$
  \item $\infty$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Let $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3+3x^2y-x$ for all real $x$ and $y$. Which of the following is true of $f$?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item There is an absolute minimum at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a relative maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{1}{3},-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a saddle point at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item There is an absolute maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item All critical values are on the line $y=x$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Find the general solution of
$$\displaystyle2\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+9\,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}-35y=0$$
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{\frac{5}{2}x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-\frac{5}{2}x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{5x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-5x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1\cos(5x)+C_2\cos(7x)$
\end{anslist}
\ep

\np
Suppose today is Wednesday. What day of the week will it be $\displaystyle 10^{{10}^{10}}$ days from now?
\begin{anslist}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item Sunday
   \item Monday
   \item Tuesday
   \item Wednesday
   \item Thursday
\end{anslist}
\ep

\end{document}


Wow, your solution is just what I needed!
It is wonderful how it aligns perfectly with my requirements. Thank you for sharing, it is been incredibly helpful. (+1 & ✓)

It works nicely, but I have a question about modifying it. Can we make answer choices as far as possible (using the whole page, except the margins), but keeping the spaces between them equal?. See the following picture, and I believe it is possible to do so. Could you help me, please? THANKS
https://i.sstatic.net/0k52RM4C.png

@Hussain-Alqatari replace \usebox{0} by \hbox to \linewidth{\unhbox0}

Oops! I encountered a problem. The code provided in the post has a required feature. The coded you provided disabled this feature. The feature is: it treats a problem and its answer choices as a single thing, they appear in the same page, and if there is no enough space in the page, it moves the problem and the answer choices to the next page. How can we fix this?

And regarding the \usebox{0}, it worked but not 100%, the contents are centered. not exactly as https://i.sstatic.net/0k52RM4C.png. Contents should move to the left, so letters (B), (C), (D), (E) will move accordingly.

@Hussain-Alqatari the code in the question has nothing to prevent a page break before the enumerate environement, this just copies that. You could put the quesion and answers in a inipage if they should all stay on one page.

I have included the good one in the post. The code in (Major Issue). Please check it. Thank you very much. With old code, problem 4 is moved to the next page, which is good, even though there is an empty space left, but that is not a sufficient space. See here: https://i.sstatic.net/pBzkWzOf.png. For new code you provided, I got same this: https://i.sstatic.net/WlKgnkwX.png, where options D and E are moved to the next page. It should be the entire thing.

@Hussain-Alqatari as i said the old code did not ensure no page breaks and neither does this, you may of course have some examples where one gets a page break and the other does not, wrap each block in a minipage then no page breaking will happen within each question.

I see, and I confirmed that you are right. What about the other adjustment, that you suggested, to replace \usebox{0} with \hbox to \linewidth{\unhbox0}. It is not exactly like this: https://i.sstatic.net/0k52RM4C.png, where the content of each answer choice is left aligned to the letter, not centered? Possible?
